# Несколько видео в одном

Tags: javascript, iframe, список, видео

Скажите, как можно скопировать данный плеер, чтобы он также показывал, как на этом [сайте](http://www.online-life.cc/581-kak-ya-vstretil-vashu-mamu-onlayn.html)? Насколько я понимаю, здесь используется `IFRAME`, но не уверен и поэтому нужна помощь.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести плеер в материале Joomla. Чтобы была возможность выбора видео, а по окончанию серии, сразу же автоматически начиналась бы вторая.

Answer (score 1):

Они используют http://uppod.ru/ так что читайте документацию и настраивайте под свой вкус.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.